# OpenId on Android

Tags: android, openid, client-side

I'd like to give my users the ability to log-in my Android app using their OpenId (have a text field like StackOverflow's and ask the user to enter his OpenId there). I've looked around a lot but could not find any libraries that allow me to implement Client-Side OpenId authentication on Android. Should I rather go for server side authentication - ie. authenticate through my own website and pass the control to the application once the authentication is done?

Thanks,

Abhinav

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/p/openid4java/

Check this link out, it is a library that allows OpenID authentication with Java programs. I have never tried it with Android, but I would assume it should work.

Comment: Does this work on Android? I am curious to find out if it does since I am also creating an app that I would like to use OpenID for authentication.

Comment: Adding the Xerces Jar (which is needed by OpenId4Java) to the Eclipse Java Build Path was making it crash (I used both - the one bundled with openid4java, and the one which is in the Eclipse plugins folder), so I ended up creating a server side implementation which directs the flow back to my app. I'll investigate it further when I'm not on such a tight deadline. Please let me know if it works for you though !

Comment: My app is a personal project, so it takes a backseat to my other projects, but either this weekend or next I can give it a shot, depends on how my workload gets distributed over the next few weeks.

Comment: I ended up abandoning that project for lack of time, sorry.